# Free document management system with workflow, approval capabilties

Tags: gratis, open-source, document-management, workflow

I need a Document Management System that has most common features of a DMS but must have the following features:

- Workflow that a document should go through and approval on various stages
- E-signature for document approval or any other means that can be audited
- Document templates, to create new documents from a template (or fillable forms to create a document from)
- On premise setup

Don't have the budget to buy any commercial product so would highly appreciate any suggestions on free for commercial use software.

Thanks!